# Background computation on iPad blocks user interface

Tags: ios, ipad, background

I'm trying to use background threds to do some computations on an iPad. 
The thing is even thou the computationa are running. The UI is blocked while they run...
What am I doing wrong.

```
[mc evaluateFormula:adapted runNo:10000];
```

This is called from an IBAction.

This is the code that is called:

```
-(void)evaluateFormula:(NSDictionary *)frm runNo:(NSUInteger)runCount
{

    self.runCount = runCount;
    self.frm = frm;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundEvalFrm) withObject:nil];

//    for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {
//        [self runFormula:frm];
//    }
//    

}

-(void)backgroundEvalFrm
{
    percentVal = self.runCount / 100;
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:20];



    for (int i = 0; i<self.runCount; i++) {
        NSInvocationOperation *op =[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runFormula:) object:self.frm];
        [queue addOperation:op];

    }

}
```

So why is the UI blocked?

Here is the thread return code... it's all in the same class

```
-(void)runFormula:(NSDictionary *)frm
{
    NSMutableString *formula = [[frm objectForKey:kFormulaExpresion] mutableCopy];
    NSArray *variables = [frm objectForKey:kVariableArray];
    NSArray *evals = [self evaluateVariables:variables];


       for (NSDictionary *var in evals) {
           NSString *sym = [var objectForKey:kVariableSymbol];
           [formula replaceOccurrencesOfString:sym withString:[[var objectForKey:@"numVal"] stringValue] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [formula length])];
    }
    //parse formula
    //NSLog(@"formula to parse:%@",formula);
    NSNumber *resNo = [formula numberByEvaluatingString];
    // NSLog(@"formula %@ the result : %f",formula,[resNo doubleValue]);
    //NSNumber *resNo = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:result];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addNewResult:) withObject:resNo waitUntilDone:NO];
}

#pragma mark -- data aggregation delegate
-(void)addNewResult:(NSNumber *)nr
{
     NSLog(@"index : %i result: %f",currentIndex,[nr doubleValue]);
    [[self delegate] didReceiveResult:nr];
    resultsArray[currentIndex]=[nr doubleValue];
    currentIndex ++;
    if (  (currentIndex % percentVal) == 0) {
        [[self delegate] percentCompleted];
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing in your runFormula

Comment: What happens if you pause the debugger when the UI is locked. Do you see the calculations being performed on the main thread or the background as you're expecting?

Comment: in runFormula I am performing some mathematical computations.

Comment: Yes I see 20 threads running. Hmm ... could it be because at the end of the thread I return the results to the main thread? I will post more code...

Comment: You should add log messages into the IBAction to see when it starts and ends. If you don't see the ending log message, the message really blocks. But from the posted code it does not look like this would take long. Maybe the interface is not really blocked but just sits there and waits for a result.

Comment: So far the results are not shown in the UI ... I'm thinking that after the computations are done I will use a local notification and then push a view that displays the results... The idea is the IBAction starts the computation threads an then just leaves them working...I will test the IBAction as you recommend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your calculations are all competing for the same resource (i.e. CPU or I/O) in an uncoordinated manner (highly probable), then you should significantly lower the maximum concurrent operation count -- try 2. chances are, they will complete using less time/energy. furthermore, the main thread will not be reduced to less than 5% of the CPU time during the period that the calculations are executing (result: more responsive UI).

Comment: @user1028028 ok, so if your UI is to responsive and the max operations is 2, you have 2xx% requested CPU usage, and the main thread will see much of the CPU time it needs (responsive!). meanwhile, the kernel has less work to do to see all 20 threads get they time they are requesting -- it's just slicing up the available CPU time and providing smaller bits to each thread as the active thread count increases (why more threads can take *longer*).

Comment: And I thought 20 threads is a small number... I'll try with 2 threads.